# Django - Spanning relationships

Tags: django, authorization

I have the following models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Employer(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, ...)
    ...

class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_name = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer)
    ...

class Psa(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Employer)
    ...
```

Each Employer owns several Psa's. Employees of a given Employer should be able to view all Employer owned Psa's.

I'm able to write a query that get's the employer_id from the request:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(employee_name_id = self.request.user.id)
    employer = employee.employer
```

With this id I can query Psa in the python shell to get the correct list of Psa's for the logged in user.

What I don't understand is how to write the query set so that generic views (ListView, DetailView...) return a filtered Psa list.

I know this must be incredibly obvious but after several day's of mucking about and reading everything I can find on SO / Django, I'm lost.

Comment: Does `return Psa.objects.filter(owner=employer)` not solve your problem?

Comment: The problem seems fairly simple. If you are a beginner in django, start with function based views insted of class based view. Might make things simpler and help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks both. Yes, I'm a beginner and did manage. to get it working in function based views. Don't know how I managed not to see the obvious. Solution is as indicated by Ashish